# Enable http2 on Nginx on Windows

Tags: nginx, http2

I am using `nginx` version `1.10.3` on windows 7. I want to enable `http2`. I have added the following in the config file:

```
 server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl proxy_protocol;
}
```

When I start nginx server, I get the following error:

```
2017/02/15 14:34:33 [emerg] 8948#6892: the "http2" parameter requires 
ngx_http_v2_module in C:\Develop\Application\nginx-1.10.3/conf/nginx.conf:64
```

Line number 64 is the same as the line specified above.

How can I install `ngx_http_v2_module` on Windows?

Comment: Official build have not make http2 module build-in on windows. If you have to use http2, you should use Linux instead.

Answer (score 6):

HTTP2 module is currently available only for Linux `nginx-full` builds.

Consider to use operating systems based on Debian or RHEL for this purpose.

Following command will help you to install `nginx-full` on Debian based OS:

```
apt-get install nginx-full
```